# Cannot submit comment

Tags: bug, android-app

When my device rotates, the submit button no longer works.

I had to select all, cut, go back to the main menu, reopen the question, find the comment, press comment again, and guess what? It rotates again. So I have to go back to home, open the question, press comment, paste while maintaining screen orientation, and submit.

- App Version: 1.0.85
- Device Manufacturer: samsung
- Device Model: SM-N900
- OS Version: 5.0 (N900XXUEBOK2)