# Duplicate bug report, different "application version": which report to keep open?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions, mobile-app

I was doing some reviews on close votes, when I came to this question.

[Cannot submit comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281225/cannot-submit-comment)

It has been proposed as a dupe of [Comment posting issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271283/comment-posting-issue)
As you can see, the original proposed question was initially posted for a different version of the app the bug reports referees to, then was updated to pinpoint that the bug is still present in the more recent versions.

This got me thinking: suppose we have two different bug reports questions, one for an old version of an Official Stack Exchange application and one for the new one. What is the current preferred way to manage this?

I think it should be enough to close the newer question (that points to the newer version) as a dupe and edit the old one to point out that the bug is still replicable in version x.y.z of the app... Can we use this approach or there is any specific reason we should prefer to keep the **newer** question open and close the older one (for example, something tied to the way bugs are tracked internally from the staff)? Are both approach the same for the Stack Exchange developer team or there is a better one?

Any official answer from the staff will be greatly appreciated, but I am open at any reasoning anyone may bring up.

Comment: I think the current way is fine, i.e. closing newer as dupe of older, and editing or commenting on the older to make it clear it still happens in newer versions. It's not very different from the sites, where bugs can span dozens and hundreds of builds without being fixed.

Comment: @ShadowWizard the whole point of the question was to ensure that the developer don't have any special reason to favor one approach on the other for technical reason we as user aren't aware of :P I was fearing that there may be an internal bug tracker that gets automatically populated from post or something similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just close one as a duplicate of the other. Doesn't really matter in which direction. (I'd err on the side of "whichever one describes the problem better", if that makes a difference.) We generally don't need multiple open posts for the same issue.

*However*, if the issue was resolved in an older version and happens again, then please open a new bug report instead of editing or commenting on the old, status-completed one.

Comment: Having official answer is also a big factor, e.g. if a newer bug report gets an answer, better close older reports as dupe of it, not the other way around.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yeah, for sure. Basically, my advice for choosing the direction is "whatever makes the most sense in context" rather than strictly "newer as a dupe of older". :)

Comment: Indeed, that's my motto as well, though sometimes others won't agree when it's not clear enough, and it can get weird as both get close votes.